# Values not propagating to parents method from child in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

Here are my classes:

```
class A(Something):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.amounts = []
        self.counts = []
    
    def common_method(self):
        amounts = self.amounts
        counts = self.counts
        print(amounts)

class B(A):
    def construct(self):
        counts = self.counts
        amounts = [1, 2, 3, 4]

        self.common_method()
```

When class `B` is instantiated, this results in printing `[]` instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

If I remove `amounts = self.amounts` from `A` I get the error `amounts` not defined. How can I get the value of amount set in `B` to persist when calling a method `common_method` from its parent class `A`.

Thanks.

Comment: `B` needs an `__init__` method that calls `super().__init__()`

Comment: `self.common_method` in `construct()` is missing `()`.

Comment: `amounts = [1, 2, 3, 4]` should be `self.amounts = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Please update your question with the full code. The code you have posted does nothing on its own.

Comment: Also, `B` doesn't necessarily need its own `__init__()`.

Comment: @quamrana I am sorry, there are over 400 lines of code so I just tried to create a basic example. :)

Comment: I mean it seems like you meant to have also posted: `b = B(); b.construct()`.

Comment: We can't run this ourselves because we don't have the `Something` class. It isn't important to the question so it (and a need for `__init__` at all in `A`) could be removed. The goal is an example we can run with unneeded code removed.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, your suggestion worked. :)

Comment: This is my first time using Object Oriented Programming practically. So, I have very little idea about what code is useful and what is not when posting a question. Thank you everyone for being patient. :)

Comment: Now that I have your attention all present and future programmers, patience is a virtue and a vital attribute for you all.

Comment: Also @RealNoob: now is the time to tidy up your code snippet. It needs to be working code that any programmer can copy and paste to verify the error you see. There are various suggestions in the comments and we could also do with the resulting full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana Please wait. I will update the question now. :)

Comment: Yes, that's `b = B(); b.construct()` what the library (https://github.com/3b1b/manim) does somwhere. It has 100s of class and different files. I had to run it in command line and get the `print()` value. I will try to make it a stand alone example. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In method `B.construct`, `count` and `amounts` are local function variables and not visible to anything outside of a single call to the function. `common_method` doesn't see them. You either need to parameterize `common_method` to take those values or, considering that `common_method` uses the object's instance variables, have `construct` fill them in.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.amounts = []
        self.counts = []
    
    def common_method(self):
        amounts = self.amounts
        counts = self.counts
        print(amounts)

class B(A):
    def construct(self):
        self.amounts = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        self.common_method()

B().construct()
```